# Frequent rate limiting (Too many requests) during normal browsing

Tags: support, rate-limiting

Recently I seem to be hitting the too many requests rate limiting while browsing on the SE network. According to the [rate limiting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) I shouldn't hit this during normal browsing and potentially my browser or an extension is sending extra requests every time I load a page.

I only have one user script installed (SOCVR's Request Generator) with TamperMonkey, and besides that I have only Dark Reader and uBlock Origin installed. Besides that, I am on my home network, and I live alone, so I shouldn't be sharing an IP address with anyone.

I don't regularly mass open tabs, and I don't have that many open for SE sites normally either. Is there anything else that could be causing these frequent rate limits? I've encountered it twice already in the last hour.

Specs: Windows 10, Google Chrome Version 70.0.3538.102

Comment: Whilst I don’t encounter this as often as you, I am also encountering this quite a bit.

Comment: Note: SOCVR's Request Generator doesn't make any AJAX requests (i.e. what might contribute to rate limiting) unless the user is specifically interacting with the UI added by the userscript. The requests it does make when you're interacting with it are to SE Chat in order to send messages into chat. In other words, it should not be contributing at all to being rate limited by SE. [In the future, the Request Generator may make a single AJAX request to a non-chat endpoint on sites using MathJax when the question title contains MathJax, but only when it's UI is being actively interacted with.]

Comment: What browser(s) and what version? Any special browser configuration (different from the default)? How many tabs are in the current browser profile (even if tabs are not actually loaded until selected)? Platform (operating system and what else may be relevant)? Can you add the relevant information to your question?

Comment: Is it [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1hrr.png)?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q yes

Comment: Hmm, I have like 30 SE tabs open usually and like 10 userscripts installed and I don't hit any rate limits. Are you sure your neighbors aren't using/hacking your wifi/ip adress? That's the only thing I can think of. I have windows 10 with chrome as well BTW.

Comment: I do hit the limit from time to time, but always because as a moderator I have lots and lots of tooling _and_ I tend to focus on larger problematic account clusters. I haven’t hit the rate limits any time recently apart from on the API (and that was my own fault, bug in my code). So this isn’t _widespread_, at any rate.

Comment: @10Rep I checked my WiFi and I don’t see any devices I don’t recognize connected to it

Comment: I also encounter this, although strangely only on MSO and not other sites, also on a private network and with only an adblocker extension, contacting stack gave the generic reply: *"While we are unable to remove or raise the rate limit for you, the rate limit isn't something you should worry too much about. In most cases, the limit should already be removed automatically by the time you've received this reply. This limit is in place to ensure equal access to all Stack Overflow users"*

Comment: Is your browser, or a browser extension, trying to improve performance by preloading pages (i.e. caching pages that are linked to) before you click on the link?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm would those preloads show up in the Network tab if the Developer Console?

Comment: As far as I can recall the only time I've been rate limited is running the "Stack Exchange Global Flag Summary" script - and I'm registered on 353 SE sites because of Smoke Detector.